# ParseObject.saveInBackground method ending with java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null while saving data to Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I checked the past posts about the same issue ([saveinbackground-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897231/saveinbackground-callback-doesnt-work)).

I am trying to get the following code working with Parse.com:

```
sendMessage.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            Log.d("Error","Completed Done");
            if (e==null){
                Toast.makeText(RecipientsActivity.this,"Message Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG",e.getMessage());
                Log.d("TAG",e.getCode() + "error code");

            }
        }
    });

}
```

This saveinBackground method is taking too long to execute and when it does, it ends with giving the following error:
i/o failure: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
100error code

I am using Parse in other pieces of the application too wherein I am fetching user contact from the Parse Core.

The message is the new class which is used to post pictures & video's on parse.com I am using the following code to create the ParseObject:

```
protected ParseObject createMessage(){
ParseObject message = new ParseObject(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID,ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME,ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENTS_ID,getRecipientsIDs());
    message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE,fileType);
    //Log.d("TAG1","Message: " + message);
    //Log.d("TAG1",mediaUri + "");

    byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(this,mediaUri);

    if (fileBytes==null) return null;
    else {
            if (fileType.equals(ParseConstants.FILE_TYPE_IMAGE)){
            fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);

     }
        String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(this,mediaUri,fileType);
        ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile(fileName,fileBytes);
        message.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE,parseFile);
       // Log.d("TAG2","Message: " + fileType);
       // Log.d("TAG2",mediaUri + "");
        return message;
    }
}
```

I checked the logs and found that the message is getting correctly created. Moreover I checked on Parse.com to see if any message class has been created there but none is being shown.

The error i am getting is this :

```
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405 W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: Upload to S3 failed. Bad Request
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405 W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseAWSRequest.onResponse(ParseAWSRequest.java:94)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseAWSRequest.onResponse(ParseAWSRequest.java:28)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.call(ParseRequest.java:267)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.Task$3.run(Task.java:199)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-25 19:23:08.695  11405-11405/ W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

After trying to debug the error, I found that if I remove the code to attach the image, it works fine. So i tried various methods to convert image to Byte[] including [image uri to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296734/image-uri-to-bytesarray) and [saving files to parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072816/saving-and-retreving-photos-and-videos-in-parse-android) but still i m not finding any luck

Comment: someone please help me.. i am struck on this for past day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else gets struck here:

I was having a conflict with the file name i was sending over to parse and the once i had given to the file when i was creating it due to which this problem was occurring.

Its a problem with converting the image to bytes and not an error on the parse side.

code to convert to bytes (following code contains fix for issues with imageview):

```
 public byte[] readBytes(Uri uri) throws IOException {
       /* // this dynamically extends to take the bytes you read
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // this is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // and then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();

        */
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
            InputStream inputStream = cr.openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPurgeable = true;

            options.outHeight = 50;
            options.outWidth = 50;
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            bitmap.recycle();
            System.gc();
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: How did you convert images to bytes can you post your code ?

Comment: @azzits i have added the code.. i ran into issue when i tried to retrieved the image so i have kept that in just in case.