# How to GetInBackground Videos from Parse and Set Download Progress on ViewHolder

Tags: android, video, parse-platform

I am querying video from Parse Backend. I want to use getInBackground to download videos from parse. And After the video are download I want to use onClick to start playing the video Immediately in my VideoView Activity

Here is the flow of my code.
Fragment for GridView

```
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("videoThumbs");
                    ParseFile video = (ParseFile)country.get("file");
                    video.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback(){
                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {

                        }

                    }, new ProgressCallback() {
                        public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                            // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.
                        }
                    });
                    String user = country.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                    //Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(video.getUrl());
                    ParseFeeds map = new ParseFeeds();
                    map.setPhone(image.getUrl());
                    map.setVideo(video.getUrl());
                    map.setUser(user);
                    phonearraylist.add(map);
```

GridViewAdapter

```
if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_image, null);
            // Locate the ImageView in gridview_item.xml
            holder.phone = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoThumb);
            holder.user = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
            view.setTag(holder);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbProgress);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Load image into GridView
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(phonearraylist.get(position).getPhone(),
                //holder.phone);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(phonearraylist.get(position).getPhone())
                .transform(new CircleTransform())
                .error(R.drawable.people)
                .into(holder.phone);
                        holder.user.setText(phonearraylist.get(position).getUser());

        // Capture GridView item click
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleVideoView.class);
                // Pass all data phone
                intent.putExtra("video", phonearraylist.get(position)
                        .getVideo());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
```

Here is my VideoView Activity

```
  Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the intent from ListViewAdapter
        phone = i.getStringExtra("video");

        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
       // mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(phone);

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mVideoView.start();
            }
        });

        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where you are downloading the video?

Comment: @MustanserIqbal on the android device the video is stored on Parse cloud

Comment: you said you want to show progress in for downloading video. so where you are trying to download the video. please share that code so i could help you. OR you need help in downloading the video?

Comment: @MustanserIqbal I need help downloading the video and I want to view the video in my videoView activity by passing the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to download the video.. and you need to figure out a way to update the progress. i can help too but now i don't have to write the code. will update in morning if you wont be able to do it.

```
public void DownloadVideoFile(String url, final String path) {

        rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/."
                + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
                int count;
                Log.e("Download ", "downloading");
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    String fileExtenstion = MimeTypeMap
                            .getFileExtensionFromUrl(aurl[0]);
                    String name = URLUtil.guessFileName(aurl[0], null,
                            fileExtenstion);
                    int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                    File folder;
                    if (!path.isEmpty()) {

                        String path2 = path.replaceAll("/", "_");
                        folder = new File(rootDir + "/" + path2);
                    } else {
                        folder = new File(rootDir);
                    }

                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        folder.mkdir();
                    }
                    File mypath;
                    if (!path.isEmpty()) {

                        String path2 = path.replaceAll("/", "_");
                        mypath = new File(rootDir + "/" + path2 + "/" + name);
                    } else {
                        mypath = new File(rootDir + "/" + name);
                    }

                    if (mypath.exists()) {
                        if (mypath.length() == lenghtOfFile) {
                            Log.e("Download ", "file already exists => "
                                    + mypath.toString());
                            return name;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Download ",
                                "file doest not exists downloading => "
                                        + mypath.toString());

                        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                                url.openStream());
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                                mypath.toString());

                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                        // long total = 0;

                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            // total += count;
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        output.flush();
                        output.close();
                        input.close();
                        return name;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

        }.execute(url);
    }
```

for downloading video and images using parse you need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072816/saving-and-retreving-photos-and-videos-in-parse-android) link

Comment: Thanks a lot I will implement your code until then.

Comment: But is it with using Parse getDatainBackground? becuase I want to load the videos from Parse Cloud

Comment: Well this code is without using parse method. you need to check this link
https://parse.com/questions/retrieving-multiple-parsefiles

Comment: Suggestion: As parse is closing their services after 10 months. then why you are still using parse. you should find an alternative.